# Send 'behalf of' mailgun in Outlook Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook, gmail, mailgun, send-on-behalf-of

I try to send email via Mailgun service.
I have domain mg.domain.com that verified in the DNS (TXT records).
I try to send email from user@some_domain.com and the credentials is the mailgun service mg.domain.com.

I defined the 'From' in the code as user@some_domain.com

In Gmail i get the email like this:

```
user@some_domain.com via mg.domain.com
```

But in Outlook i get:

```
user=some_domain.com@mg.domain.com on behalf of user@some_domain.com
```

Why?

I want to get in outlook the same as in Gmail, with the '='.

**Actually,** i want to send from info@mg.domain.com, i mean:

```
user@some_domain.com on behalf of info@mg.domain.com
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `via` and `on behalf of` messages, because the server that sent the email is different from the domain of the user's email. Gmail and Outlook are showing that extra information to the end user and there is no standard on how to display that. They are displaying it the way that fits their needs: Gmail using `via` and Outlook using `on behalf of`.

The bad news is that you can't control it.

> Actually, i want to send from info@mg.domain.com, i mean:
>
> ```
> user@some_domain.com on behalf of info@mg.domain.com
> ```

Don't think you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks @uzbekjon, but do you know way to remove the '=' sign in outlook and get like Gmail?